# Restricted access for other user roles

Tags: admin-menu

I have made some restrictions on other user roles than the administrator. I've made it because I use WooCommerce.

I have added the following code to my themes functions.php file, and it works fine.

```
function remove_menus()
{
    global $menu;
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    if($current_user->user_level < 10)
    {
        $restricted = array(__('Pages'),
                            __('Media'),
                            __('Links'),
                            __('Custom Post Name'),
                            __('Comments'),
                            __('Appearance'),
                            __('Plugins'),
                            __('Users'),
                            __('Tools'),
                            __('Settings'),
                            __('Posts'),
                            __('Produkter'),
                            __('Kontrolpanel'),

        );
        end ($menu);
        while (prev($menu)){
            $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
            if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
        }// end while
    }// end if
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus');
```

I want to hide "WooCommerce -> Settings", but I cannot figure out how to make it happen in the above code? Can someone help me?

Comment: This highly depends how and where the menu is registered. You'll have to dig into WooCommerce core, file an [edit] and add this info to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually its very simple ex:

```
// only administrator
if ( ! current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_woocommerce_menu_pages', 999 );
    function remove_woocommerce_menu_pages() {
        remove_submenu_page('woocommerce', 'woocommerce_settings');
    }
}
```